# IMSdroid registration issue in android

Tags: android, sip

I am looking for an open source `sip` project to add my `android application`. I found `IMSDroid` project, downloaded the source code and build on `Android ADT`. 
But when I install the application on my `android phone`, I cannot register to sip provider(sip2sip.info). I tried on both `3G` and `WiFi` networks but `Sign-in` always fails. I followed the instructions at this link https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/wiki/sip2sip_info but no success
By the way, I downloaded `CSipSimple` application too. I simply filled the registration settings and it worked! I mean `CSipSimple` application can register to `sip2sip` while `IMSdroid` cannot.
I also tried SIP stack of Android. There is a sample application using sip stack of android, called `SIPDemo`. I also tried this application but its registration also failed.
What is the issue about? I don't want to use `CSipSimple` because to me it seems more complex than `IMSDroid`.

Comment: I also followed the link, which you mentioned and the IMSDroid is work for me.

Comment: @Hsin-Hsiang I couldn't solve my problem. Finally, I installed Asterix sip provider on my local PC and connected to it.

Comment: I found that sometimes i need to change UDP to TCP when i use 3G not wifi to makecall. I plan to install the Asterix after some function tests the IMSDroid^^

Comment: @Hsin-Hsiang By the way, do you know is it possible to excluding the sip provider? can IMSDroid communicate peer-to-peer without the need of sip provider?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to VoIP... I find a disscussion related to this application. http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/issues/detail?id=282